# How do I change Spotlight search engine?

Tags: google-chrome, spotlight, search, google

when I use Spotlight, it offers to "Search web for: " (something like that, my system is german). When I use this feature, Chrome pops up and searches with the Yahoo search engine.

Chrome is the right choice, but I want so search with Google. My Browser Settings state that Google is my default search engine.

Does anybody know where this might be configured?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fire up Safari and check the settings for the default search engine. For me that is google and searching the way you described it for me opens safari (currently my default browser) with a google search.

The option is right there on the first settings tab. I included an image detailing where to find it (sorry for the german):

[image: Explanation of where to find the setting]

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! But why would the Safari settings decide what kind of search engine Chrome uses?

Comment: I _guess_ this is because what spotlight actually does is not so much to tell the default browser to 'search for X' as to just open a url that it constructed from your query and the search engine configured 'system-wide'. Since every search URL is constructed a little differently doing it that way makes some sense, but not making this clear anywhere to me is bad policy on their part. Or negligence.